# Dual horizontal scrollbar shows up, only 1 wanted

Tags: html, css, materialize

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s8">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
            <!-- I get a horizontal scrollbar within this element ONLY -->
            <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; white-space: nowrap">
                <div class="treegen">1</div>
                <div class="treegen">2</div>
                <div class="treegen">3</div>
                <div class="treegen">4</div>
                <div class="treegen">5</div>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 100px; max-height: 350px;">
                <!-- I get a horizontal scrollbar at this element too... -->
                <ul class="tree"> <!-- very wide element -->
                    DATA IN THE UL
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a single scrollbar, only on the element that has `overflow-x: auto;`, however I also get it on the element with the tree class (or it's parent). I don't want that second scrollbar. I want the height scrolling on the 'tree' or its parent but the width scrolling I want that to be done at the same time on both the divs (`<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; white-space: nowrap">` and `<div style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 100px; max-height: 350px;">`).

Comment: use one overflow instead of multiple.  overflow-y: auto will create a scrollbar when the content increases from the pre defined height e.g height:300px. Same with overflow-x: auto will create a scrollbar when the width increases from the predefined width. Hope this clears your issue.

Comment: @hunzaboy That does not solve my issue. I need to use both for the design.

Comment: Can you show a working demo or a mockup of what you need? A rough image will work just fine...

Comment: @hunzaboy I already fixed it by setting the width of the div holding the ul tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by limiting the div that the `<ul class="tree">` is in by the width of the other div (`<div style="margin-bottom: 5px; white-space: nowrap">`).

Result (when limited to 500px):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s8">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
            <!-- I get a horizontal scrollbar within this element ONLY -->
            <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; white-space: nowrap">
                <div class="treegen">1</div>
                <div class="treegen">2</div>
                <div class="treegen">3</div>
                <div class="treegen">4</div>
                <div class="treegen">5</div>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; min-height: 100px; max-height: 350px; width: 500px;">
                <!-- I get a horizontal scrollbar at this element too... -->
                <ul class="tree"> <!-- very wide element -->
                    DATA IN THE UL
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```